# razorengine - run without compiling into dynamic assembly

Tags: razorengine

In previous versions it was possible to use `Parse()` for the job.

See old documentation at https://razorengine.codeplex.com/

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

Sexy. Now however there is only Run() and RunCompile(). And for Run() to work the template needs to be compiled already - I cannot pass in the template only the template's name.

As I do have razor templates where nearly no re-use is happening I would like to be able to **NOT have to compile those templates into dynamic assemblies** and load them into the app domain. The temporary files issue is another reason.

**Is this still possible using RazorEngine?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NOT have to compile those templates into dynamic assemblies
>
> Is this still possible using RazorEngine?

No and it never was.
Parse will compile the template, load and execute it exactly as RunCompile does. Even worse Parse doesn't cache the template so the loaded assembly is not even accessible (=leaked memory)

> I cannot pass in the template only the template's name

You can via an extension method if you add `using RazorEngine.Templating` to the top of your file. Than you can use one of the "RunCompile" examples of the quickstart: https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine#quickstart

> I do have razor templates where nearly no re-use is happening

You should take a look at the isolation API and restart the isolated AppDomain from time to time. On the other hand (if you don't want to pay the cost of AppDomain-boundary) you can handle AppDomain restarts yourself and use the regular API.

Hope this helps,

matthid (Disclosure: RazorEngine contributor)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying Parse() also created a dynamic assembly. I wished there was a way to not create an assembly for any tiny string I want to "translate" :-) ### Will look into the isolated appdomain. Do I still need to write my own CachingProvider or TemplateManager in order for the automatic appdomain recycle to happen?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do: Just counting the number of accesses or regular restarts (once a day/week/month) should be pretty straight-forward. Any custom logic depending on number of re-compiles of a single template will require more code. But there is no out-of-the box experience to recycling (as it always pretty much depends on your needs).